# Software to see ALL the JS errors on site like console

Tags: javascript, web-development

First the context:
I’m looking for JavaScript errors in my sites.

What I am doing now:
Looking at the console (Firefox Inspector). It works, but… I have to go PAGE BY PAGE and see the results (console) on each one. In a site with 3 pages it’s not a big issue but when you have 40 or more, it turns you crazy.

So … **Do you know a program which automatizes this?** I am looking for the same but trying to avoid the page by page situation. If so, something Open Source will be even better.

All the suggestion and even your own experience about HOW to handle this will be much appreciated. And hey … I’m learning :D

Comment: What kind of error are you looking for? If you are looking to simple syntax errors on load, have a look at phantomjs: you can write your scripts to drive it through the pages

Comment: @MarcoL Sorry for the late response! I did not see yours. So, with phantomjs I could walk over ALL the pages of the site? I do not want to charge page by parge and look at the console. I want to look at the console but seeing all the errors of all the pages? Is this possible? Do you have a reference? Thanks a lot! And remember that I´m learning haha.